# Nodejs : TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectID' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am facing problem with mongodb while parsing ObjectId in Node.js.
I think problem in mongodb's package.

Following are the error code.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectID' of undefined
at exports.viewerData (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\routes\linkAPI.js:76:30)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at next (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
at Function.proto.process_params (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
at next (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
at serveStatic (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:59:14)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Node Application\Code Admin\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
```

can anybody tell me what was issue?

Answer (score 0):

you have a construct in your code that looks like: 
name[objectID] or name.objectId

and name is undefined

Comment: Yes , exactly i got , require('mongodb').BSONPure  = undefined.  but How i resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Try `require('mongodb').ObjectID` without `BSONPure`

Answer (score 0):

you have a property that is named ObjectId instead of a property with the value of an ObjectId.

so for example....

`{ ObjectId: value }`

instead of

`{property: ObjectId(value)}`

objectId is a structure that describes a value in mongodb's driver this could be causing problems with the parser if you have for some reason named a property this way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was that I defined `const Schema = mongoose.Schema();` instead of `const Schema = mongoose.Schema;` (without trailing parenthesis). So I was getting the error when calling `Schema.Types.ObjectId`